# intellij application verification error while using the same .p12 and provisioning that I used on flash builder what can I do?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, intellij-idea, starling-framework

Im quite sorry for the long tittle, I've been stuck with that for a while now, we started using flash  builder for some mobile applications, so i got the mobile.provisioning file and the .p12 certificate, it works perfectly on flash builder, but  now we moved to this new sw and some things need to be set differently. apparently I'm not setting it right on intellij or am I missing something else? I looked for this and I only get solutions for Xcode

Im setting those at project settings - modules -ios the .p12 as keystore certificate

Also I've tried running the application on simulator and works fine

thanks for your attention
  Kind Regards JFB

Comment: Try to upgrade to IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) and import your working Flash Builder project following the tutorial (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Adobe+Gaming+SDK)

Comment: THANKS!!! you have just saved my career as game developer